# close the batch file command scripts

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have the following batch file script code to run. When I run it, it executes successfully, but does not close the cmd window automatically. What should I add to have it close the window automatically?

```
::Copy Files Made Or Modified Today
@echo off
setlocal
set source=c:\src
set dest=c:\dest
pushd "%source%"
set t=%date:~4%
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d') do call :PROCESS "%%a"
goto :eof
popd

:PROCESS
for /f %%j in ('echo %~t1') do set d=%%j
if "%d%"=="%t%" copy %1 "%dest%"
goto :eof
```

Comment: How are you invoking this batch script?

Answer (score 0):

Test this if you are clicking on the batch file.

```
@echo off
::Copy Files Made Or Modified Today
setlocal
set source=c:\src
set dest=c:\dest
pushd "%source%"
set t=%date:~4%
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d') do call :PROCESS "%%a"
cls
goto :eof
popd

:PROCESS
for /f %%j in ('echo %~t1') do set d=%%j
if "%d%"=="%t%" copy %1 "%dest%"
goto :eof
```